# How to access a column after subsetting data frame?

Tags: r

It has to be really simple but it looks like my mind is not working properly anymore.

So, what I would like to do is to store one of the columns from `mtcars` as a vector but after subsetting it. I need one line code for the subsetting and assigning a vector.

That's what I would like to achieve but with one line:

```
data <- mtcars[mtcars[,11]==4,]
vec <- data[,1]
```

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mtcars[,11]==4` would be the row index and by selecting the column index as '1', we get the first column with subset of rows based on the condition.

```
 mtcars[mtcars[,11]==4, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
vec<-mtcars[mtcars[,11]==4,][,1]
```